# How to add custom Filter in website odoo10, instead using of website category filter?

Tags: odoo-10

I am created a custom field on product form , which is selection field (product for sale or rent ).

i want this in my website filter in dropdown menu .

what is the easiest way to create a custom filter n showing its result ?

i dont want to add this field in website product category.

```
class PostProperty(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'
property_for = fields.Selection([('sale', 'Sale'),
                                 ('rent', 'Rent')],`enter code here`
                                'List Property For')
```

I would like to serach products by sale or rent on webiste.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
@http.route(['/page/buy'], type='http', auth='public',
            website=True)
def property_for(self, **post):
    property_values = []
    propeperty_obj = request.env['product.property_for']
    domain = []
    if post.get('search'):
        domain += [('name', 'ilike', post.get('search'))]


    keep = QueryURL('/page/buy', property_for=[])
    values = {'property_for': sale, 'keep': keep}
    if post.get('search'):
        values.update({'search': post.get('search')})
    return request.render('product.template.property_for', values)



if rent:
        property_for = rent
        products = Product.search(domain, limit=ppg, offset=pager['offset'], order=self._get_search_order(post)).search([('product.property_for', '=', rent)])


    elif rent:
        Product.search(domain, limit=ppg, offset=pager['offset'], order=self._get_search_order(post)).search([('product.property_for', '=', sale)])    

    else :
        property_for = None
    products = Product.search(domain, limit=ppg, offset=pager['offset'], order=self._get_search_order(post))
```